# Sort results of query ASC

Tags: php

I have this code and want to sort the results `ASC` on the field `user.LName`

```
$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.FName, user.LName, user.HerbalifeID, user.UplineS, registratie.PartnerFName, registratie.PartnerLName, registratie.NaamVIP1, registratie.NaamVIP2, registratie.NaamVIP3 FROM registratie INNER JOIN user ON registratie.userID = user.UserID AND registratie.eventID=".$id);
```

I have tried placing this at the end of the statement: `ORDER BY user.LName ASC");`  This did not work. I'm in the learning stage and don't know how to solve this.  How can I do this?

Comment: Really? In seriousness, did you do any of your own searches first?

Comment: Sorry for this question Jon, I have tried at the end with:    ORDER BY user.LName ASC");    but won't work. I'm in the learning stage.

Comment: If you want to order by LName as per your question, why are you trying to order by ticketSDate? Also, define not working? The query is failing? The sorting isn't what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY user.LName ASC` is correct. You're probably just missing a space between it and the id. Check for the sql error

```
$sql = "
  SELECT user.FName, user.LName, user.HerbalifeID, user.UplineS, registratie.PartnerFName, registratie.PartnerLName, registratie.NaamVIP1, registratie.NaamVIP2, registratie.NaamVIP3 FROM registratie INNER JOIN user ON registratie.userID = user.UserID AND registratie.eventID=$id
  ORDER BY user.LName ASC
";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$res) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you verry much four your help! Now it works like I want it. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

First thing before asking here is to use [Google](http://google.com/).
I searched for

> Sort results of query ASC

And this is the first result: [SQL ORDER BY Keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

> The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns.
>
> The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the DESC keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The query runs after a checkbox is selected. Depending on the $id, the query should search the results and sort ASC.
I tried in several ways to do this with the ORDER BY function but I can't find the solution. I now it will be something stupid, but think it has someting to do with the .$id at the end of the code.
Here is the whole code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['chk'])=="")
{
?>
  <script>
  alert('Er moet tenminste één checkbox geselecteerd zijn !!!');
  window.location.href='../EVENT/eventIndex.php';
  </script>
<?php
}
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$chkcount = count($chk);
?>    
<?php  
for($i=0; $i<$chkcount; $i++)
{
$id = $chk[$i];

$res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.FName, user.LName, user.HerbalifeID, user.UplineS, registratie.PartnerFName, registratie.PartnerLName, registratie.NaamVIP1, registratie.NaamVIP2, registratie.NaamVIP3 FROM registratie INNER JOIN user ON registratie.userID = user.UserID AND registratie.eventID=".$id );

while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
?>
```